# Обращение к php-скрипту с клиента

Tags: php, ajax

Со странички клиент посылает запрос к php-скрипту на сервере.

```
$('[target=export]').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            url: "<?= HTTP::getURL('cabinet', 'cards', 'export_excel')?>"
            });
        });
```

Этот скрипт начинает работать,при этом у клиента не грузиться ни одна страница сайта с браузера в котором сделал запрос.

Пример.

Открываем страницу в хроме,щелкаем по искомой ссылке(скрипт запустился). В хроме сайт не загружается(пока скрипт исполняется).Если в это же время откроем тот же сайт в опере-все грузиться. Тоже самое если наоборот сделаем-запрос в опере,проверка в хроме.

От браузера это не зависит.Проверял на лисе,хроме,опере,ослике.

php-скрипт

```
        set_time_limit(999);
        $export=ORM::for_table('cards')
            ->where('cards.client_id',$this->client['id'])
            ->find_many();
        $export_array=$array_temp=array();
        foreach($export as $ex){
             array_push($array_temp,$ex->uid,$ex->balance);
            array_push($export_array,$array_temp);
            $array_temp=[];
            }


        //крафт дока и заполнение названиями столбцов
        $excel2 = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
        $excel2 = $excel2->load($current_file); // Empty Sheet
        $excel2->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
        $excel2->getActiveSheet()
                ->SetCellValue('a1','Уникальный идентификационный номер карты')
                ->SetCellValue('b1','Баланс');
        //Заполняем таблицу
        $i=2;
        foreach($export_array as $d){
            $excel2->getActiveSheet()
                ->SetCellValue('a'.$i,(string)$d[0])
                ->SetCellValue('b'.$i,(string)$d[1]); 
            sleep(1);
            } 
        ///сохранение документа в xlxs
        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel2, 'Excel2007');
        $objWriter->save($current_file);
```

слип,чтобы выявить что скрипт работает и при этом сайт не загружается.

В чем проблема может быть?в прошлом вопросе устроили демогогию не по теме пришлось удалить..

Comment: Что делает ваш ajax запрос?

Comment: @Visman,отправляет запрос к скрипту на сервере(вроде в посте код приведен,не?))

Comment: Сделайте просто `$.ajax("<?= HTTP::getURL('cabinet', 'cards', 'export_excel')?>")`.

Comment: @Visman,такая же реакция

Comment: У вас сессия используется в скриптах php? Если да, то вероятно она блокируется при выполнении этого скрипта и не дает работать другим копиям php с сессией этого пользователя.

Comment: @Visman,это возможно как её разблочить для этого скрипта - временно конечно

Comment: [session_write_close()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-write-close.php)

Comment: @Visman,но это равноценно тому что пользователь выйдет-или я ошибаюсь

Comment: У вас скрипт должен в начале сделать всю работу относящуюся к сессиям (считать данные, записать изменения, если нужно), потом  `session_write_close()`, а уже потом этот скрипт может сколь угодно долго выполнять любые действия, на сессию это не повлияет. Если же у вас работа с сессией (запись в нее) продолжается до окончания выполнения скрипта, то нужно подумать о переписывании алгоритма работы это скрипта.

Comment: @Visman,спасибо. Буду думать)